# how to add the dimmed background found in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, ios5, uialertview

Im making a custom dialog thats similar to UIAlertView, and was wondering if anyone had any ideas how I can emulate the dimming background as in the photo below.

[image]

Comment: Mind if I ask what the custom dialog is for?  The best way to get the effect behind a UIAlertView is to use a UIAlertView.

Comment: its a dialog with custom content

Comment: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/custom-alert-views.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that you should be very careful to have a real justification for [redoing something that is already there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here), but if you really need it, it's easy:

Create a PNG image with the same size as the targeted device's screen, with alpha. TFill the image black, and add a radial opacity gradient, so that in the center, it is relatively transparent, while towards the screen edges it'll be more opqaue. This effect is called vignetting. Maybe there even is a vignetting filter on your preferred image editor, which you could use on a completely transparent image.

This image approach also has the benefit of allowing you to use completely different effects of fading away the background.

Create a `UIImageView` with the vignette image, and transparent background. Add the view to your app's Window, on top of all other views, but below your alertView:

```
UIImageView *vignetteView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"vignette.png"]];
vignetteView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
vignetteView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; //this means users won't be able to touch the UI elements below
[self.view.window insertSubview: vignetteView belowSubview: myAlertView];
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd recommend that you do your best to avoid the need for a custom modal dialog.  You can usually give your feedback contextually within the flow of your application's actual views.

If your app targets iOS 5 only, UIAlertView offers three new styles to allow text input, secure text input, or a user name and password combo.

If you still need a custom modal alert, and you're looking to stay consistent with the iOS look and feel, and maintain resolution independence, I'd recommend that you avoid using static graphical assets.  Instead, take the (somewhat hackish) approach of subclassing UIAlertView, and adding your own controls to it.  You can find examples of doing this [here](http://www.skylarcantu.com/blog/2009/08/14/custom-uialertview-color-chooser/) and [here](http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/custom-uialertview-with-uitableview/).